# jQuery scrolling sidebar, stop and start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so i have just made a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/06qwtgt6/1/ - it has a main container and a sidebar and the sidebar scrolls perfectly as I need. However I'm stuck with how to make it stop as the right bar hits the top and once the bottom of the container comes up at hits the bottom of the right bar needed it to then continue to scroll out of view with the main container if that makes sense.

Thanks in adavnce

UPDATE: I found this http://www.waypointarts.com/blog/2013/06/29/fixing-a-side-bar-while-scrolling-until-bottom - which is something i am after but of course for my scroll parallax-content part of the code. Really stuck with this so help would be greatly appriciated all! :)

UPDATE:

Attempted update, its not working but im trying - thanks everyone for any help.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
            //var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            //$('.parallax-content').css('bottom', '+' + ((scrolledY * 1.3)) + 'px');

            if (scroll < $('#story-intro').offset().top) {

                $('.parallax-content').css('bottom', '+' + ((scroll * 1.3)) + 'px');

            } else if (scroll > length) {

                $('.parallax-content').css({
                    'top': '0'
                });

            }

        });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div id="story-intro-first" data-type="background" data-speed="10"></div>
    <div id="story-intro-second" data-type="background" data-speed="10"></div>
    <div id="story-intro-third" data-type="background" data-speed="10"></div>

    <div class="parallax-content" data-type="content">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h3>Two reporters use Skype to put Kiribati in the spotlight</h3>
            <p>There's a small island in the middle of the Pacific Ocean called Kirbati. It's home to about 100,000 people and in roughly 40 years the entire island will be under water due to rising sea levels from climate change.</p>
            <p>The people that live there will have no other option than to abandon their homes and their lives to find refuge in neighboring countries and traditions will be washed away forever.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /********************************************************************************/
    /* Parallax Scrolling */

    // Cache the Window object
    var $window = $(window);

    $('[data-type]').each(function () {
        $(this).data('offsetY', parseInt($(this).attr('data-offsetY')));
        $(this).data('Xposition', $(this).attr('data-Xposition'));
        $(this).data('speed', $(this).attr('data-speed'));
    });

    // For each element that has a data-type attribute
    $('div[data-type="background"]').each(function () {

        var $self = $(this),
            offsetCoords = $self.offset(),
            topOffset = offsetCoords.top;

        $(window).bind('scroll', function () {

            if (($window.scrollTop() + $window.height()) > (topOffset) &&
                 ((topOffset + $self.height()) > $window.scrollTop())) {

                var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $self.data('speed'));

                if ($self.data('offsetY')) {
                    yPos += $self.data('offsetY');
                }

                var coords = '50% ' + yPos + 'px';

                $self.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

            };

        });

    });

    // For each element that has a data-type attribute
    $('div[data-type="content"]').each(function () {

        $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
            var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();

            $('.parallax-content').css('bottom', '+' + ((scrolledY * 1.3)) + 'px');
        });

    });


 });
```

CSS

```
.main-container {
    position: relative;
}

    .main-container .parallax-content {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        width: 30%;
    }

    .parallax-content .sidebar {
        float: right;
        background: #ffffff;
        padding: 1em;
    }

#story-intro-first {
        background: url(http://placehold.it/2080x1028) 50% 0 fixed;
        min-height: 600px;
        height: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1920px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    #story-intro-second {
        background: url(http://placehold.it/2080x1028) 50% 0 fixed;
        min-height: 600px;
        height: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1920px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    #story-intro-third {
        background: url(http://placehold.it/2080x1028) 50% 0 fixed;
        min-height: 600px;
        height: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1920px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 5;
    }
```